# How to use IntegerRange as part of unique constraint in a Django 2.2 model

Tags: django, unique-constraint

I understand that Django 2.2 is outdated. I am in the midst of migrating.

Having said, that I still need to temporarily add new constraints to prevent invalid data for time being.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.ranges import IntegerRangeField
class ProjectStructureWbsIslandGap():
    series = models.ForeignKey(ProjectStructureFasSeries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_island = models.BooleanField(default=True) # island or gap
    level_3_range = models.IntegerRangeField(default=(1, 9999)) # 1-9999
    line_number_range = models.IntegerRangeField(default=(1, 9999)) # 1-9999

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
            fields??
            conditions??
            ),
        ]
```

so what i want is these two constraint,

whenever create new or update existing `ProjectStructureWbsIslandGap` record, within the same parent `series` and of the same `is_island` value, no two records can have overlap in terms of the IntegerRangeField `level_3_range`.

whenever create new or update existing `ProjectStructureWbsIslandGap` record, within the same parent `series` and of the same `is_island` value, no two records can have overlap in terms of the IntegerRangeField `line_number_range`.

so under the unique constraint, how should i fill in `fields`, and `conditions`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do seems to have been added in 3.0   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/constraints/.

If you do not use bulk_update and bulk_create in your project, you can always override the .save() method as a temporary solution to enforce your conditions